# How to get date in "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" format?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, datetimepicker

i have date in this format 2014-09-20 04:45:20 +0000 and i need to convert this to yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ format.I tried with the following code

```
NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
            NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:@"2014-09-20 04:45:20 +0000"];
            NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

but date giving me null value..

I am geting 2014-09-20 04:45:20 +0000 from time picker so anythg needs to be done on picker side will also help me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
NSString *aStrDate = @"2014-09-20 04:45:20 +0000";
NSDateFormatter *aDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
aDateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z";
NSDate *aDate = [aDateFormatter dateFromString:aStrDate];
aDateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";
NSLog(@"%@",[aDateFormatter stringFromDate:aDate]);
```

Comment: This is not right. The 2nd string will be in local time but will have `Z` added to make it appear like it is in UTC time.

Comment: @Yasika What if Nsdate *date = 2014-09-21 05:58:18 +0000 how to convert this to yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'