# Parsing a date string gives [__NSDate length] unrecognized selector exception

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have an `NSDictionary` that holds a date like this:

> "2015-05-23 21:04:11 +0000"

[image]

and I'm trying to parse it like:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:[item valueForKey:@"enddata"]];
```

I also tried changing the last line to:

```
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:[[item valueForKey:@"enddata"] stringValue]];
```

but my error is always the same:

> [__NSDate length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78ec0170

I've seen posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348965/how-to-read-a-nsdate-in-from-a-string), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999396/how-to-parse-a-date-string-into-an-nsdate-object-in-ios), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25945402/how-to-get-date-in-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-sssz-format), and [many more](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nsdateformatter%20string). I've tried with different formats such as:

1. @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"
2. @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzzz"
3. @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
4. @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +zzzz"
5. @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"
6. @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
7. @"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"
8. @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a"
9. @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"
10. @"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss zzzz"

but still getting the same `SIGABRT`

Does anyone have a clue what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would hazard a guess that `item[@"enddata"]` is already an `NSDate` object and not an `NSString` object.

Verify with:

```
NSLog(@"enddata is type %@", NSStringFromClass([item[@"enddata"] class]));
```

Also don't use `valueForKey:`, but instead use `objectForKey:` or the newish access syntax I've used above.

Comment: oh, me = dumb... I'm so familiarized with Android than I didn't really wonder I could extract so "difficult" object from a dictionary.... Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 0):

This

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"2015-05-23 21:04:11 +0000"];

NSLog(@"date: %@", [dateFormat stringFromDate:date]);
```

works fine for me.

`NSLog` is your friend.  Maybe you should `NSLog` the value of `item`, or the value of

```
[item valueForKey:@"enddata"]
```

or even

```
[[item valueForKey:@"enddata"] stringValue]
```

since if the latter is an `NSString` in the desired format then calling `dateFromString` with it should work fine.